# How to get the Folder name in Sublime Text Build

Tags: php, regex, localhost, sublimetext3

I'm working in a project and I need every time to check the browser, so I added a build to sublime text that will build the current file i'm working on in the browser "localhost/folder_name/current_file", but its not working properly, here is the code i'm using:

```
{ 
    "cmd": [
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
        "localhost/$folder/$file_name"
    ] 
}
```

So the ($folder) means the folder I'm working on... But in the browser it's showing like this: http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/index.php

the $folder is showing the full path of the current file, but I only want the folder name "MyProject" so when I build the file it has to be like this:
http://localhost/MyProject/index.php

How I'm going to do it?

Thank you..

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `$folder` with `${folder/^.*\\\\//}` works on windows. Try:

```
{ 
    "cmd": [
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
        "http://localhost/${folder/^.*\\\\//}/$file_name"
    ] 
}
```

It tries to remove characters up to the last backslash present in `$folder`.

Source: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#placeholders-for-variables

Comment: in my testing on Windows, I had to use `http://localhost/${folder/^.*\\\\//}/$file_name` to get it to work

Comment: @KeithHall does it try to escape backslashes twice or does it actually try to delete upto last occurence of  `\\` (*two* backslashes)?

Comment: `^.*` from the beginning of the string, match any character any number of times, ```\\``` JSON escape for a single slash, ```\\``` another JSON escape for a single slash = ```\\``` in regex = a literal slash, `/` begin replacement pattern, `/` end replacement pattern (i.e. replace with nothing)